# Phonegap iphone App

Tags: jquery, iphone, sql, html, cordova

I'm currently building an iPhone app in HTML 5 and jquery. What would be the simplest way to pull in the latest football fixtures and results and is ideally free?

I thought maybe an rss feed then put them into a database?

So that I can use them later ?

Quite vague I know but just thinking of different options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think RSS Feeds + Database is a good option.

> You can also search for some apis which provides you live data, so
>   that you can directly fetch it and show it in your application.